# Android Activities, Tabs, Back Button

Tags: android, android-activity, tabs, stack, back

I am writing my first Android app.  It's a port of an iPhone app which has 3 tabs at the bottom, call these A, B and C.  Tab A has 4 child activities (A1, A2, A3, A4) , tab B has 3 child activities and Tab C has 2 child activities.

For the Android app, I don't really want to show the iPhone style tab bar at the bottom.  In fact I'd rather have no tab bar at all (so I can use more of the screen) and instead use the Menu button to swap between activities A, B and C.

I'm really struggling to choose the best method to implement this which will also need to handle the back button correctly.

I've read the Android developer notes on Activities and tried this out (using the intent flags to disable the 'slide left' effect)  This works for switching between A1, B1, C1, but if you've navigated A1, A2, then C1 i don't know how to make the Back button go to A2 (it goes to A1)

I've also read about using Tabs and tried a test with this.  However the back button is not handled and simply exits the app.  I realise I can handle the Stack myself and override the Back button and that I'll need to use ActivityGroups. But I've not found any good examples of how to handle the back button in the ActivityGroup and also read that theres a bug in handling the back button if one of the Activities in the Group is a ListActivity, which I also intend to use.

Any help or pointers would be appreciated to help get me started.

Comment: Could you show how you call the subactivities this might give a clue. As in general problem you described happens with TabHost but shouldn't happen if you just call activities via menu.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I go about using the menu button. In your main activity have something like this:

First, make a new android xml file and set the type to menu (its one of the dropdowns in eclipse), then the menu.xml file will automatically be made in the right place.

Open up the layout, and add your 3 items (one for each page you want to switch to)

```
    // Menu button pressed
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.page1:
        startActivity(new Intent(this, page1Activity.class));
        break;
    case R.id.page2:
        startActivity(new Intent(this, page2Activity.class));
        break;
    case R.id.page3:
        startActivity(new Intent(this, page3Activity.class));
        break;
    }
    return true;
```

Where page1Activity and the rest are the other classes.

Make sure that in your Id section of the layout you have @+id/page1, etc...

Just add those activities to your manifest and it should work. The back button works fine with this (though I havent tried with a listview. With a listview you should just have a finish(); when you select something to avoid multiple lists)

To switch subpages use something like this:

```
public void page1aPressed(View button) {
    Intent nextPage = new Intent();
    nextPage.setClassName("com.example",
            "com.example.page1a");
    startActivity(nextPage);
```

When you press back it just goes to the previous activity. Maybe I'm thinking of this wrong but it works for me.

Comment: Hello, thanks for replying. The code I have is exactly like what you have posted above. My problem is that each of the three pages have sub-pages. It's handling the navigation of those that's giving me the problems :( Ie Page1 press button to go to sub page eg Page 1a (NOT page 2 or page 3), then Menu page 3, press back and it goes to Page 1 (not page 1 sub page)

Comment: OK, this sounds like it will handle going back up the sub-activities. How do I make it handle if they go 1a, 1b, then menu and choose page 3 then menu and choose page 1. I want it to show page 1b at that point (ie the last active sub-page they accessed) but it is showing 1a because my menu is hard coded to start activity page1a. Will I need to use 3 stacks to keep track of which sub-activity they are at and make 1a, 2a, and 3a check the stack when they are resumed to see which activity they should display?

Comment: I've been looking at Fragments (using Support/Compatibility package for platform < 3.0) and think I'm going to try and implement this.  I did read that you can't make a MapView a fragment, but I also saw some workaround code to get that working too (as I'm going to use a MapView as well). Thanks again for taking the time to reply.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you use TabHost it's quite hard thing to handle and I wouldn't recommend that
2. If you use Context Menu than calling each activity normally (!not withing activity group) should put the Activity to the Activity Stack and make standard functioning of Back button available.

Alternatively you can imitate bottom menu just by a separate menu View which you include to all the layouts which will avoid TabHost limitation but will give the same look.